# Keras for creating CNN

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am working with Keras to build my own CNN to identify cats and dogs. I've created a folder called "cats-and-dogs". This folder is in the same directory as is my jupyter notebook (***"cats-and-dogs"*** folder & ***Keras.ipynb*** notebook both are in Anaconda3 folder). Now the further tree of folders looks like this:

***cats-and-dogs/***
|_______________train/
|_______________|_______cats/
|_______________________|_____1.jpg
|_______________________|_____2.jpg
|_______________________|_____...
|_______________|_______dogs/
|_______________________|_____21.jpg
|_______________________|_____22.jpg
|_______________________|_____...
 
|_______________test/
|_______________|_______cats/
|_______________________|_____41.jpg
|_______________________|_____42.jpg
|_______________________|_____...
|_______________|_______dogs/
|_______________________|_____61.jpg
|_______________________|_____62.jpg
|_______________________|_____...
 
|_______________Valid/
|_______________|_______cats/
|_______________________|_____81.jpg
|_______________________|_____82.jpg
|_______________________|_____...
|_______________|_______dogs/
|_______________________|_____101.jpg
|_______________________|_____102.jpg
|_______________________|_____...
 
***Keras.ipynb***
|____
|____
...

### My code that gives out error is:

### train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory('cats-and-dogs/train', target_size=(224,224), classes=['dog','cat'], batch_size=10)

***Expected output:*** Found 80 images belonging to 2 classes.
***Actual output:*** Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.

Comment: Why does it show 0 images even if there are 80 images in "train" subfolder ?

Comment: Try replacing the path with `os.path.abspath('cats-and-dogs/train')`, I'm pretty sure it needs an absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `classes` parameter to `classes=['dog','cat']`, this will look for `dog` and `cat` folders, but your folders are called `dogs` and `cats`, so it makes sense that it finds no images.

Either remove the `classes` parameter for the generator to auto-detect the class names, or put the right classs names that match your folder names.

Comment: Thank you so much ! i've been stuck with this problem from past 2 days. You were very helpful. I did make a silly mistake. but now corrected it by renaming classes list elements properly.Thank you so much again. :)

Comment: @VinitaKumari Please make sure to accept answers if they are useful to you and solve your problem.